# Postgres: how to check for records in time buckets for multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have a POSTGRES table with roughly the following shape:

```
sensor_id |         recorded_at
----------+--------------------
        A | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
        A | 2020-01-01 00:30:00
        B | 2020-01-01 01:00:00
        C | 2020-01-01 01:30:00
      ... |                 ...
```

Given a

- Start time
- End time
- Bucket width
- List of sensor ids

I'd like to write a query that slices the range `[start_time, end_time]` into sub-intervals (buckets) of width `bucket_width` and, for each bucket, check if each of the sensors in the list had a record with `recorded_at` during that bucket.

So for example, assuming inputs of

- Start time = `'2020-01-01 00:00:00'`
- End time = `'2020-01-01 02:00:00'`
- Bucket width = `'1 hour'`
- List of sensor ids = `['A', 'B', 'C']`

the query should return something like

```
                  t1 |                  t2 | A_count | B_count | C_count
---------------------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------
 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 01:00:00 |       2 |       0 |       0
 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | 2020-01-01 02:00:00 |       0 |       1 |       1
```

I don't need the actual count, so I imagine `LIMIT 1` will show up somewhere. I just included it in the example to help make it clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: Presimably, you mean `'2020-01-01 02:00:00'` instead of `'2020-01-01 00:02:00'`.

Comment: Whoops, yes! I'll edit the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses `generate_series()` to generate the rows, then a `left join` to bring the table, and finally conditional aggregation to get the count by sensor:

```
select s.ts ts1, s.ts + interval '1 hour' ts2,
    count(*) filter (where sensor_id = 'A') a_count,
    count(*) filter (where sensor_id = 'B') b_count,
    count(*) filter (where sensor_id = 'C') c_count
from generate_series('2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2020-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp, '1 hour') s(ts)
left join mytable t on t.recorded_at >= s.ts and t.recorded_at < s.ts + interval '1 hour'
group by s.ts
```

Note that this would generate an extra record (from `02:00:00` to `03:00:00`) as compared to your desired results. If you want to avoid that, you can slightly modify the `generate_series()` arguments, like:

```
...
    from generate_series(
        '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
        '2020-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp - interval '1 second', 
        '1 hour'
     ) s(ts)
...
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This doesn't take the sensor IDs as an input, but that's not a big issue. Any way to limit the counts?